# What replaces "with"?

Tags: javascript

I know `with` is supposedly a "Bad Part" but I never cared, because I just used it carefully (ditto, btw, with `var` statements in blocks). Now, I understand that `with` has been banished from EcmaScript 5.0 strict mode.

Here's my use-case: I have a library that exports some 20 or 30 functions. Most of my code never uses any of the library but the parts that do, use them *a lot*.

Right now, my code looks like:

```
with (mylib) {
    f1(f2(f1(), f3())); // five or 10 more lines like this
}
```

To be compliant, I will have to...

a) Move all of the functions to global scope (yuck).

b) `mylib.f1(mylib.f2(mylib.f1(), mylib.f3()));` (which is verbose)

c) `var x = mylib; x.f1(x.f2(x.f1(), x.f3()));` (which is slightly less verbose but less meaningful).

Please tell me that there's some better solution out there now.  What I want is some way to export the contents of a object into a level of scope (which is *exactly* what `with` was for).

**EDIT:**

Something I should have made clearer.  I don't want people to explain to me why I don't want to do what I do want to do; I want people to explain to me *how* to do what I do in fact want to do.

The thing is, for reasons beyond my control, the exports of the library all have *very* recognizable names.  Instead of calling them f1, f2, and so on, let's say they're called Bobs_Library_Function_F1, Bobs_Library_Function_F2, and so on.

I just don't want a lot of code that looks like

```
Bobs_Library.Bobs_Library_Function_F1(Bobs_Library.Bobs_Library_Function_F2(Bobs_Library.Bobs_Library_Function_F1(), Bobs_Library.Bobs_Library_Function_F3()));
```

(The real names aren't that bad, they're quite beautiful actually, and prefixing cuts into that.)

Anybody who *seriously* disagrees here, well, I hope you never use `$.whatever` when you are supposed to be using `jQuery.whatever` because that would make you look like a big ole hypocrite.

I'm thinking of using `$$.f1`...

**FURTHER EDIT**

Seriously, thanks for all the input, but I'm not looking for a poll on whether (a), (b), or (c) is the best. I'm looking for choice (d) that does what `with` does so well.

Do I at least get block-scoping out of strict mode?

Comment: bite the bullet and update your code with option b). Anything else is just burying your head in the sand and hoping the tide won't come in.

Comment: The simple solution is to not use the 'strict' statement where you want to use legacy javascript- that is the reason 'strict' can be applied selectively in a script environment.

Comment: `with` is not suggested for use for a reason.  You could always emulate it by manually assigning `mylib`'s properties, to `window` and then removing them when you're done.

Comment: @Rocket -- now *there* is an actual suggestion!  Write it up as an answer (and put in something about "stash any current properties in window with the same name") and I'll upvote it, if not accept it.

Comment: Based on your edits, then, the answer is either "too bad" or "don't use strict", depending on how married you are to using strict mode. There's are certainly some alternatives being suggested here, some are adequate some are performance-killers, but if you don't like any of them then the best alternative may be no alternative. Saying that no one has proposed suggestions is not true.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an even easier way without messing with the global scope.

Comment: @Alex Nolan  -- nope, you're still messing with global scope.

Answer (score 9):

`with` is bad, because inside the block, you have no idea where the variables are coming from.  Is `f1` equal to `mylib.f1` or `window.f1`?

I would suggest going with option `b)`.  You can use `c)` if you want, it may help with long object names, but `b)` is the way to go.

**EDIT**: Another suggestion is to use option `a)`, but then remove the references from window when you're done.  Also, be careful not to overwrite any existing properties in `window`.  You can throw them into another object for save keeping, if you want.  Building upon [@Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095399/what-replaces-with/7095553#7095553):

```
var bkupWin = {};  // Object to store existing window properties

for(var key in myLib) {
    if(myLib.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        if(window.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          bkupWin[key] = window[key];  // Backup current property
        }
        window[key] = myLib[key];  // Add property to window
    }
}

f1(f2(f1(), f3()));

for(var key in myLib){
    if(myLib.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        delete window[key]; // Remove property from window
        if(bkupWin.hasOwnProperty(key)){
          window[key] = bkupWin[key];  // Restore old property
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read my (first) edit.  Don't why I don't want to do what I do want to do; tell me how to do what I do in fact want to do.  Since *everybody* is doing what you did, I'm thinking of reversing your downvote, on London-Police-can't-arrest-everybody grounds.

Comment: @Malvolio: Everybody is suggesting similar things, because that is how you accomplish this task without using `with`.  If you want to use `with`, go ahead, just don't use `strict` mode.

Comment: -1 changed to +1 for at least giving it a shot.  The mods are beginning to piss me off.  "Not constructive", pfft.

Answer (score 4):

According to Mozilla:

> Using with is not recommended, and is forbidden in ECMAScript 5 strict
>   mode. The recommended alternative is to assign the object whose
>   properties you want to access to a temporary variable.
>   Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Two things to take away:

- Strict mode is the only place where it is forbidden in ECMA5
- The recommended alternative is your option (c)

The only reason it is not "meaningful", as you say, is the selection of a variable like `x` - the least descriptive thing possible.

```
 mylib.f1(
      mylib.f2(
         mylib.f1(), 
         mylib.f3()
      )
 );
```

Is already more readable, and doesn't really take more space than `with` did. If you really, really want to chain method calls, have these methods return `this`:

```
var mylib = {
  f1: function () {
     /* do stuff */
     return this;
  },
  f2: function () {
    /* do stuff */
    return this;
  }
}

// then you can chain calls, organize with indentation
mylib
 .f1()
 .f2();
```

Comment: Good thinking, but as it happens, mylib generate objects that belong to *another* library, one that already uses chaining.

Answer (score 3):

None of the examples are quite readable, I'd prefer something like this:

```
var 
    param1 = mylib.f1(),
    param2 = mylib.f3(),
    result = mylib.f2(param1, param2);
mylib.f1(result);
```

Of course the variable names should be renamed to something what their content describes. This creates a lot of code, but it is readable and even more important it is easier to debug. To minify it use special programs, which are even able to optimize the code in some way.

Answer (score 1):

If these are all applied to the same object like your example you could write wrapper methods like

```
function f4() {
    return this.f1(this.f2(this.f1(), this.f3()));
}
```

and add it to `mylib`. So at least the ugliness would be contained to your object.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could make a few facade functions to your library that would reduce some of the noise of option b or c. So, this...

```
mylib.f1(mylib.f2(mylib.f1(), mylib.f3()));
```

Would become...

```
mylib.f123_facade();
```

Other than that, I think you may just have to put up with the clutter.

Comment: Thanks, but almost all the code is unique -- `f123` would only be called once.

Answer (score 0):

If the library isn't too intrusive (overwrites anything) you can export the whole library to the global scope:

```
for (var key in myLib) {
    if (myLib.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        window[key] = myLib[key];
    }
}
```

EDIT: Also you have to be careful if the library uses `this`.

EDIT2: You could force your own scope and imitate the with function:

```
function doWith(func, myLib) {
    for (var key in myLib) {
        if (myLib.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this[key] = myLib[key];
        }
    }

    func.apply(this)
}
```

And an example:

```
var lib = {
    init: function(param1) {
        console.log(param1);
    },
    f2: function() {
        return "hi";
    }
};
doWith(function(){init(f2());},lib)
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/msm595/AenUc/1/

EDIT3: NVM, Rocket is right OTL.

Comment: That's actually what I was doing (option (a) I called it), until I realized how much more neatly `with` solved the same problem.

Comment: Inside `doWith`, `this` is `window`, so it still adds `myLib`s properties to `window`.

Comment: Wow, your second solution was so subtly flawed, it took me 15 minutes to see the problem.  That `func.apply(this)` isn't doing *anything* that `func()` wouldn't.  `this` is `window`, you're just putting everything in global scope again.

Comment: XD.... OTL. Lets just say my brain stopped working for a while...